# failed to get directory listing in filezilla ftp

Tags: website, ftp, filezilla

I am trying to connect to my web-space via ftp and i get the following errors although it is a successful connection...i have disabled my windows firewall but it is not working. I need to publish my webpage what is the problem?

```
    Error:  Connection timed out<br>
    Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: This is not a programming question. The port 21 connection (outgoing) may be succesful, the server can't initiate a connection back to you, probably because you're behind NAT. Set your client to use passive mode or PASV.

Comment: `Command: PASV`

Comment: Tell your client to send that to the server, posting it here it won't help much. Or are you trying to tell you did so?

Comment: just make sure from host, username, password, port and command plus  permissions